# UV Mesh Not Unwrapping Correctly

Tags: uv

So all I want to do is unwrap this UV mesh correctly so I can export it to Photoshop, however once i unwrap it I get a mess of jumbled shapes that leaves no reason whatsoever. I made a video of it so that someone could help me if they would like.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=diXBAGYHFBM&feature=youtu.be

I apologize in advance my voice is very low.

Comment: not sure it's a problem, you have 2 3x3 squares, and 4 3x1 rectangles. to see your islands better, add some margin in your unwrapping setting (F6 or T panel after unwrapping)

Comment: sorry wasnt a good example, i uploaded a better one here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=diXBAGYHFBM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: also changed to the correct video in the pos

Comment: tried adding the margins and it just shows every block as an individual one now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mesh is displaying dots along some of the edges. There are quite a few in the video, I marked a few below. These are actually face centres and show that there are hidden faces:

[image]

In edit mode select everything and choose <kbd>W</kbd>> *Remove Doubles* and this should get rid of the extra faces by merging close vertices.
From the blend file you supplied I also found many internal faces:

[image]

These need to be deleted (<kbd>X</kbd>> *Faces*). You can then also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals to make sure all your faces are pointing the right way
 before unwrapping again.

Comment: It helped get rid of some of the crazy shapes but still not unwrapping like it should, here is another video with the progress so far. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuHm9dmAaOI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @JordanLeeBurnes I would suggest uploading the blend file to http://pasteall.org/blend/ and adding that to the original post.

Comment: http://pasteall.org/blend/34354 there ya go

Comment: thanks a bunch man I had no idea I had to worry about stuff that was inside the whole object you are a life saver.